# "Simply connected" like condition for isotopy

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mapping-class-group

I'm looking for literature regarding a locally compact Hausdorff topological space $X$ where any two embeddings $f,g:[0,1]\to X$ with fixed boundary points $f(0)=g(0),f(1)=g(1)$ are isotopic.

If we replace "isotopic" with "homotopic" then this is equivalent to being simply connected.

I'm not even sure what keywords to search for.

Comment: Small note: this is only equivalent to simply connected if your definition of simply connected is that $\pi_1(X,x) = 1$ for all $x \in X$ -- usually "simply connected" also requires that the space be path connected!

Comment: I do not think there is a standard terminology for this. Two observations: If $X$ is a (connected) manifold of dimension $n\ne 3$ and curves $f, g$ are "locally flat" (say, $X$ is a smooth manifold and curves are smooth) then your condition is equivalent to simple connectivity of $X$. When the dimension is $n=3$, then your condition never holds.

Comment: Care to elaborate or point me to a source that explains this?

Comment: For $n=3$ this is simply the existence of nontrivial knots in $S^3$. For $n=2$, this result is due to Epstein (homotopy implies isotopy, Acta Math, 1966). I will look for references in higher dimensions when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is standard terminology for this (I wouldn't be surprised if there is, I'm just not very well-versed in this stuff!), but here's one way to think about it.

Let $x_0 = f(0) = g(0)$ and $x_1 = f(1) = g(1)$.

Let $P = \operatorname{Hom}([0,1],X)$ be the space of continuous maps $[0,1] \to X$, endowed with the compact-open topology, and let $P_{\bullet}$ be the subspace of those paths $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ such that $\gamma(0) = x_0$ and $\gamma(1) = x_1$. Let $E$ be the subspace of $P$ consisting of topological embeddings, and let $E_{\bullet} = E \cap P_{\bullet}$.

[Quick side note: it's important for what follows that $X$ be "nice" -- your assumption of locally compact Hausdorff is sufficient!]

Now:

- A homotopy from $f$ to $g$ is the same as a path from $f$ to $g$ in $P$
- A homotopy from $f$ to $g$ relative to the endpoints is the same as a path from $f$ to $g$ in $P_{\bullet}$
- An isotopy from $f$ to $g$ is the same as a path from $f$ to $g$ in $E$
- An isotopy from $f$ to $g$ relative to the endpoints is the same as a path from $f$ to $g$ in $E_{\bullet}$

So, the condition you want is equivalent to $E_{\bullet}$ being path connected! Hope this helps :)